# "Host key does not match configured key" when uploading file to SFTP using WinSCP command

Tags: ssh, sftp, public-key, winscp, fingerprinting

I'm using SSIS to upload files to SFTP. I'm using command prompt to execute the WinSCP command. Code is as below:

```
winscp.com /command  "open sftp://username@sftp.client.com/ -privatekey="H:\Share\CT_SFTPPrivateKey\privatekey.ppk" -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 256 71yCy6d6qLSxxX5dZ/+99On+8xiDnJ4NG7tXmKiOMik=."""  "put -delete  H:\Share\WorkingFolders\BOPIS\*.csv /sc/production/incoming/segment/" /log="H:\Share\WorkingFolders\BOPIS\WinSCP.log" "exit"
```

I'm getting Host key does not match configured key exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` at the end of your host fingerprint should not be there.

```
-hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 256 71yCy6d6qLSxxX5dZ/+99On+8xiDnJ4NG7tXmKiOMik=""
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a complete valid command-line template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl) for you.